# I want to broadcast a signed meta transaction in a smart contract

Tags: transactions, ethereum, signature, contract

I would like to implement a function like approve in tokens with ETH.

Instead of depositing ETH on the contract, we want to transfer money directly from the address of the user who signed the contract.

We believe that these are feasible with the current metatransaction and are developing them.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract MetaTransaction {
    function executeMetaTransaction(
        address to,
        uint256 value,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 nonce,
        uint256 gasPrice,
        uint256 gasLimit,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) public {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(to, value, data, nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit)
        );

        address signer = ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);

        require(signer != address(0), "Invalid signature");

        (bool success, ) = signer.call(data);

        require(success, "Transaction failed");
    }

    function sendEther(address payable _to, uint256 _amount) public payable {
        require(msg.sender.balance >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        
        _to.transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

This does not work for ETH transfers.

How can implement the functionality my looking for?
Please help.